# How do we define select statement as a variable in dbt?

Tags: dbt

Hi I am trying to define a select statement in a set variable in dbt,
can any one suggest how to set sql query as a variable in dbt  and how to access those variables in below CTEs?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `call statement` and get the result in a variable with `load_result`

Here is an example of retrieving only one field from the select statement:

```
{%- call statement('my_statement', fetch_result=True) -%}
      SELECT my_field FROM my_table
{%- endcall -%}

{%- set my_var = load_result('my_statement')['data'][0][0] -%}
```

Then you can use `{{ my_var }}`

You can play with `['data'][0][0]` depending on the rows and columns that your select returns

Comment: Hey! Do you wrap it in a macro, and then refer to it as {{var}} inside a model .sql?

Comment: When I try to access [data][0][0] I get 'None' has no attribute 'data', but if I log data only (without indexes), dbt compile runs without errors and I can see list a of tuples printed in the console as expected. Do you know the reason for this problem?

Comment: Hi, Is this solution applicable for superset also or only for dbt?

Answer (score 9):

You could consider embedding your SQL statement in a macro and call that macro in your models.

```
{% macro get_data() %}
    {% set query %}

        select
            column_a_boolean,
            column_b_varchar
        from my_table

    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(query) %}
    {# execute is a Jinja variable that returns True when dbt is in "execute" mode i.e. True when running dbt run but False during dbt compile. #}
    {% if execute %}
    {% set results_list = results.rows %}
    {% else %}
    {% set results_list = [] %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ return(results_list) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

You can then use the above macro in a model.
For example, in a model below, we UNION records returned by the macro if a value in a column `column_a_boolean` is equal `true`.

```
{% for record in get_data() %}
    {% if record.column_a_boolean == true %}
        {% if not loop.first %}
            UNION ALL
        {% endif %}
            SELECT
                record.column_b_varchar
    {% endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do you implemented run_query() ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dbt_utils.get_column_values`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source):

```sql
{%- set my_var = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
    table = source('source_name', 'object_name'), 
    column = 'my_col',
    where = "my col != 'some_value") -%}

{%- for x in my_var %}
    select 
        '{{ x }}' as test
    from {{ source(x, 'object_name') }}
    {% if not loop.last -%} 
        union all 
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Make sure your `packages.yml` file contains `dbt-utils`:

```yaml
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: 1.0.0 # latest version as time of writing, change as needed
```

Then run `dbt deps` to initialize the package:

```bash
$ dbt deps
```

The `run_query` [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) has a nice example as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% macro hello() %}

{% if execute %}
    {% set results = run_query("select 'hello'; ").columns[0].values()[0] %}
{% endif %}

select {{results}} as id;

{% endmacro %}

output 
results will contain hello
```