# Store result of a query in a variable ( jinja)

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to put the result of a query in a variable but it doesn't work.
I am not sure what to do so it returns 0 as expected. Any ideas? I am using dbt and jinja.
With the below code the **results_list** variable is `(Decimal('0'),))`

**MACRO**

```
{% macro source_freshness(model, column_name) %}
{% set freshness_query %}
SELECT COUNT 0 AS count
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(freshness_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

{{ return(results_list) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

call in a **model**:

```
{% set freshness_query_test = source_freshness(ref('model'),'date') %}

{% if count in freshness_query_test == 0 %}
do this
{% else %}
do that
{% endif %}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hi, how do we define select statement as a variable in dbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007239/hi-how-do-we-define-select-statement-as-a-variable-in-dbt)

Comment: thank you so much. I have been trying both options in different ways but it doesn't seem to work. The call statement works but the thing is that I am using a macro which has a query with CTE. I've tried adding the whole query in the call statement but it doesn't work. I thought it was the same but I was wrong so I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you are missing `{% set freshness_query %}` in your macro

`{% macro source_freshness(model, column_name) %}
{% set freshness_query %}
SELECT COUNT 0 AS count
{% endset %}`

Comment: ouch! I think I missed it when changing the query to publish. I have found a way to do this though. See the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this work for Superset too or only for dbt?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help with this. I have not been able to find a direct answer but what I have done is to add the macro in a separate model, and then use the call statement logic in the shared answer [Hi, how do we define select statement as a variable in dbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007239/hi-how-do-we-define-select-statement-as-a-variable-in-dbt)