# How to use a SELECT statement to set a variable in DBT that is later used in a FOR loop?

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm trying to create a variable that's the number of months between today and '2019-01-01', and then use that number in a loop range.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007239/how-do-we-define-select-statement-as-a-variable-in-dbt), but still can't get it to work for some reason.

```
{%- call statement('test', fetch_result=True) -%}
      SELECT DATEDIFF('month', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), CAST(NOW() AS DATE)) as months
      FROM {{ ref('my_table') }} LIMIT 1

{%- endcall -%}

{%- set num_months = load_result('test')['data'][0][0] -%}

SELECT
    {% for month_offset in range(0, num_months) %}
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS month_{{ month_offset + 1 }}{% if not loop.last %},
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
FROM {{ ref('my_table') }} LIMIT 1
```

SQL Fluffer picks up an error at the very beginning "Unrecoverable failure in Jinja templating: sqlfluff.core.templaters.jinja.UndefinedRecorder object has no element 0."

And when i run the code, I get:
`TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

i tried doing `run_query` too:

```
{% set num_months = run_query("SELECT DATEDIFF('month', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), CAST(NOW() AS DATE))
      FROM {{ ref('dim_product') }} LIMIT 1") %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both `load_result` and `run_query` return "dicts" so to access the scalar value of the query, read the `data` element from that result. i.e. do the load query but then pull the wanted `data` value from the result dict:

```
{%- call statement('test', fetch_result=True) -%}
  SELECT DATEDIFF('month', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), CAST(NOW() AS DATE)) as months
  FROM {{ ref('my_table') }} LIMIT 1

{%- endcall -%}

{%- set result = load_result('test') -%}
{%- set num_months = result['data'][0][0] -%}

SELECT
    {% for month_offset in range(0, num_months) %}
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS month_{{ month_offset + 1 }}{% if not loop.last %},
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
FROM {{ ref('my_table') }} LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Aw, no luck, still same error :< "'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: after the set num_months' insert: `{% do log(num_months, info=true) %}` to check what value is being returned

Comment: also try using the int function `{%- set num_months = int(result['data'][0][0]) -%}` to force the value to integer

Comment: still same, unfortunately. I tried wrapping it in int() all over the place, but doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: do you actually get a value in num_months? did it print out?

Comment: if i just do SELECT {{num_months}} FROM table, yes, it builds a table with just that value. But doesn't seem to want to use it in the FOR loop.

Comment: ok, i just did SELECT type({{num_months}}) and it threw an error `function type(integer) does not exist` ... so it's clearly an integer %\ .... then wtf :(((
I think there's just no way to use the variable with {{}} inside the loop macro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256337/discussion-between-adrian-maxwell-and-raksha).

Answer (score 0):

As answered on GetDBT Slack channel by Owen:

```
{% set now = modules.datetime.datetime.now() %}
{% set reference_dt = modules.datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1) %}
{% set num_months = ( (now.year - reference_dt.year)*12 + now.month - reference_dt.month ) %}

SELECT
    {% for month_offset in range(0, num_months) %}
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS month_{{ month_offset + 1 }}{% if not loop.last %},
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
FROM {{ ref('my_table') }} LIMIT 1
```